# JTable- Overriding prepareRenderer while applying the default Nimbus styling?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer, nimbus

I'm using Nimbus. To make things simple with overriding prepareRenderer on a JTable, the first thing I usually do is get the Component from the super method, so I can tweak only the properties I want while leaving everything else the same.

The problem is once I change a style property on that component, like background color, it does every single render after that with that color because it apparently is reusing that JLabel. So every new cell that renders becomes red, not just the one I wanted.

I've always used HTML to avoid this, but I need to manipulate the JLabel's foreground/background properties. Does anybody have a block of code that sets all the default properties for a renderer, and I can use that in the *applyDefaults* method placeholder I have below?

I am using Nimbus so I don't know if that makes things harder. But I want the foreground/background for selected/unselected and odd/even rows to be rendered to their defaults, and everything is manipulated after that.

```
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {

        final Component c =super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        applyDefaults(c, row, col); //what do I need to restore default styles here? 

        boolean highlightRed condtion == //some boolean condition
        boolean isSelected = //calculate whether row is selected

        if (c instanceof JLabel) { 
            if (isSelected == false && highlightRed) { 
                ((JLabel) c).setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
```

UPDATE: Went with camickr's suggestion and I built a convenient default interface for Nimbus JTables. the restoreDefaultRenderer resets all the properties to the default Nimbus colors and alignments.

```
public interface JTableCustomRender {
    static final Color foreGround = Color.black;
    static final Color oddBackGround = new Color(255,255,255);
    static final Color evenBackGround = new Color(242,242,242);
    static final Color selectedForeGround = new Color(255,255,255);
    static final Color selectedBackGround = new Color(57,105,138);

    //static final ImmutableList<Class<?>> leftAlignTypes = ImmutableList.of(String.class, Date.class, DateTime.class);
    static final ImmutableList<Class<?>> rightAlignTypes = ImmutableList.of(Integer.class, Double.class, Float.class, BigDecimal.class);

    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int viewRow, int viewCol);

    public default Component restoreDefaultRenderer(JTable table, Component c, int viewRow, int viewCol) { 

        if (c instanceof JLabel) { 
            final boolean rowSelected = Arrays.stream(table.getSelectedRows()).filter(i -> i == viewRow).findAny().isPresent();

            JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
            if (rowSelected) { 
                label.setForeground(selectedForeGround);
                label.setBackground(selectedBackGround);
            }
            else { 
                if (viewRow % 2 == 0) { 
                    label.setBackground(evenBackGround);
                }
                else { 
                    label.setBackground(oddBackGround);
                }
                label.setForeground(foreGround);
            }
            Object value = table.getValueAt(viewRow, viewCol);

            if(rightAlignTypes.contains(value.getClass())) { 
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            }
            else { 
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            }
        }

        return c;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. override isSelected, hasFocus etc. (methods from XxxTableCellRenderer are accesible for prepareRenderer too), 2. convert index from view to model for row and column too, 3. 1st. code line in prepareRenderer should be if (myTable.getRowCount > 0) have to test that 4. model cat returns value harcoded in rightAlignTypes, isn't it == getColumnClass 5. all conditions should be prepared as value, because renderer is quite intesive painting (mouse. key, events implemented in APIs) 6. for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it does every single render after that with that color because it apparently is reusing that JLabel.

Correct, which is why you need an else statement to reset the background back to the table default.

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for examples of how you might do this so that you also take into account the selection color of the row as well.

> Does anybody have a block of code that sets all the default properties for a renderer

The basic code would be:

```
c.setBackground( getBackground() );
c.setForeground( getForeground() );
```

You would do that for any property that you are manually tying to override.

Comment: Yeah I'm somewhat familiar with these concepts, but I guess I'm looking for a "silver bullet" that I can put in a default interface and reuse everywhere. Is it possible I can clone() the JLabel and manipulate that? That way the original is not affected?

Comment: Well, I don't think you want to clone the label every time, since the point of a renderer is to be efficient so you don't keep creating components every time a cell is rendered. The default renderer also has some method overridden to make painting more efficient. You could create your own custom renderers that reset all the properties to the defaults.

Comment: Okay I'll need to play with this.. my goal is to maximize reusability and not to create more classes. But I'll see what I can do here...

Comment: Okay, maybe I was being a bit too zealous, this really is not that bad. I gathered the different context colors for a Nimbus JTable and created an interface to easily invoke resetting the component's default properties. Code is above...

Comment: @Thomas N. 1. not good code, you don't need that, 2. why is there odd/even highlighter, defaults from Nimbus aren't good, 3. Object value = table.getValueAt(viewRow, viewCol); should be 1st code line, 2nd. should be convert index from view to model (valid in the case that/if you are sure that row count in the view is more than zero)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code overriding the method prepareRenderer(), hope it helps someone:

```
public class MyJTable extends JTable {
    private final Color lineSelectedBackgroundColor = new Color(153,204,255);
    private final Color cellSelectedBackgroundColor = new Color(51,153,255);
    private final Color cellSelectedForeGroundColor = Color.BLACK;

    private final Color oddRowBackgroundColor = new Color(224,224,224);
    private final Color evenRowBackgroundColor = Color.WHITE;

    private final int lowThreshold = 33;
    private final int highThreshold = 66;

    private final boolean debugEnabled = true;
    private void log(String msg){ if(debugEnabled){ System.out.println(msg); } }

    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        int selectedRow = super.getSelectedRow();
        int selectedColumn = super.getSelectedColumn();

        if(row==selectedRow && column==selectedColumn){
            component.setForeground(cellSelectedForeGroundColor);
            component.setBackground(cellSelectedBackgroundColor);
        }else if (row==selectedRow){
            component.setBackground(lineSelectedBackgroundColor);
        }else{
            if(row % 2 == 0) {
                component.setBackground(evenRowBackgroundColor);
            }else{
                component.setBackground(oddRowBackgroundColor);
            }
        }

        if(column==AppData.hyundaiTableStockIndex) {
            String stockStr = getValueAt(row, AppData.hyundaiTableStockIndex).toString();
            try{
                int stockValue = Integer.valueOf(stockStr);
                if (stockValue < lowThreshold) {
                    component.setBackground(Color.RED);
                } else if (stockValue > lowThreshold && stockValue < highThreshold) {
                    component.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                } else if (stockValue > highThreshold) {
                    component.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                log("parsing failed.");
            }
        }

        return component;
    }
}
```